# Data from array to each td cell iof table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table and want to past data from array to each cell. Only one data to one cell.

```
  <table style="border: 1px solid #333">
    <tr>
      <th>#1</th>
      <th>#2</th>
      <th>#3</th>
      <th>#4</th>
      <th>#5</th>
      <th>#6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I try js which do not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var pole = [11,22,31,4,5,6];
  $.each(pole, function(i, val){
    $('table td').html(pole[i]);
  }
});
```

Can ask help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` for current object

```
 var pole = [11,22,31,4,5,6];
  $("table tr td").each(function(i, val){
    $(this).html(pole[i]);
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q982roo8/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use correct selector to target tds in each iteration. use `.eq()` selector along with index property of each iteartion to do that:

```
var pole = [11,22,31,4,5,6];
 $.each(pole, function(i, val){
 $('table td').eq(i).html(val);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/02e4hmey/)**

Comment: In addition, instead of calling `pole[i]` you can directly use `val`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nad1xpgf/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      var pole = [11,22,31,4,5,6];
      $.each(pole, function(i, val){
        $('table td').eq(i).html(pole[i]);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript get the element by its id then replace innerHTML by the the td tags and the values that you want.